# SQL 'Total Count' and Count of Rows not present in another table GroupBY

Tags: sql-server

I have tables as follows:

```
create table rrr_br(br_id nvarchar(10), location nvarchar(10))
create table rrr_profile(profileid nvarchar(10), br_id nvarchar(10))
insert into rrr_br values('AAA', 'CHN')
insert into rrr_br values('BBB', 'CHN')
insert into rrr_br values('CCC', 'CHN')
insert into rrr_br values('DDD', 'MDR')
insert into rrr_br values('EEE', 'MDR')
insert into rrr_br values('FFF', 'MDR')
insert into rrr_profile values('111', 'AAA')
insert into rrr_profile values('222', 'BBB')
insert into rrr_profile values('222', 'FFF')
```

Now i need to fetch from 'rrr_br' table..."Location" Wise Total Number of br_id and Number of br_ids not present in  'rrr_profile' table

```
Select  location 'LOCATION', 
    cnt 'Total Vehicles', 
    cnt 'Vehicles Not Processed'
from    (select location,Count(*) cnt  
from    rrr_br  vh(nolock)      
group by location ) B
```

Thanks.

The expected result is as follows:

```
  Location| Total Vehicles| Vehicles Not Processed|
  -------------------------------------------------
 CHN    |   3   |   1       |
 MDR    |   3   |   2       |
```

Comment: Could you add the expected result?

Comment: :Location| Total Vehicles| Vehicles Not Processed|
------------------------------------------------------------------
CHN       |       3       |               1        |
MDR      |       3       |               2        |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN` to determine if vehicle processed, `COUNT(*)` to include all rows and `COUNT(col)` to exclude null value.

```
SELECT rrr_br.location, 
    COUNT(*) AS Total, 
    COUNT(*) - COUNT(rrr_profile.profileid) AS NotProcessed
FROM rrr_br
LEFT JOIN rrr_profile ON rrr_br.br_id = rrr_profile.br_id
GROUP BY rrr_br.location
```